# Ejecutable en PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

tengo una aplicacion de escritorio hecha con python 3.6 y en windows 7 de 64 bits, el problema que tengo es al correrla en equipos con sistema operativo windows de 32 bits esta no corre, mientras que en equipos con windows de 64 bits corre a la perfeccion, como podria solucionar esto? existe alguna manera de crear un ejecutable que funcione en ambos sistemas?

Comment: No es algo propio de Pyinstaller. en general una aplicación de 64bits no va a funcionar en un sistema de 32, al contrario si es posible gracias a Wow64. Si quieres que funcione en sistemas con arquitectura de 32 bits necesitarás instalar Python 32 bits , instalar en él todas las librerías necesarias para tu programa y pyinstaller y crear la app con ésta versión.

Comment: pyinstaller compila en base al computador en donde se ejecuta, es decir, si lo corres en uno de 32 bits, de 32 bits quedará tu programa, lo mismo con el de 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

¿Has instalado Python3 de 64bits? Creo recordar que tuve problemas una vez con eso. Prueba a instalar la version de 32bits de Python, sea o no tu pc de 64bits, y vuelve a installar `PyInstaller` para esa version de 32bits. (La opcion `-F` te genera un *.**exe** único por cierto)

Entiendo que PyInstaller te compila el codigo a la arquitectura que sea tu interprete y no el del sistema operativo.

Quedate con Python *32bits*, 64bits solo para soluciones muy especificas de momento si necesitas compatibilidad.